# How to solve telegram api java api error 404

Tags: java, telegram, telegram-api

I need help with this error when working with Telegram API

```
Error removing old webhook
at org.telegram.telegrambots.util.WebhookUtils.clearWebhook(WebhookUtils.java:112)
.....
Caused by: Error deleting webhook: [404] Not Found
```

I have created a bot with telegram,

Service class:

```
@Service
public class Test1Api {


    @Autowired
    public Test1Api(@Value("${bot.username:}") String botUserName, @Value("${bot.token:}") String botToken) {
        try {
            TelegramBotsApi telegramBotsApi = new TelegramBotsApi(DefaultBotSession.class);
            telegramBotsApi.registerBot(new Test1Bot(botUserName, botToken));
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

here is the bot class

```
public class Test1Bot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {

private final String botUserName;
private final String botToken;

public Test1Bot(String botUserName, String botToken) {
    this.botUserName = botUserName;
    this.botToken = botToken;
}


@Override
public String getBotUsername() {
    return botUserName;
}

@Override
public String getBotToken() {
    return botToken;
}

@Override
public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
    System.out.println(update.getMessage().getText());
    System.out.println(update.getMessage().getFrom());
}
```

When i try to run my code i have an error from telegram
attaching here
The error from telegram:
What can i do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you provide a good token.
You can check it by manually requesting your telegram bot to delete webhook.
[POST] https://api.telegram.org/bot<your_token>/deleteWebhook

If everything is alright you should get as a response:

`{
"ok": true,
"result": true,
"description": "Webhook is already deleted"
}`

Then you'll be sure that your token is correct but you're providing it wrong.
Maybe check your application.properties

However if your response is different (eg. Not Found) - there's problem with your telegram token.